# ValueError "Testing not found" when trying to install CATS addon

Tags: add-on

I am trying to install the CATS addon. It appears as installed in the addons, but I can't activate it because of this `'Testing' not found` error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In short: The addon isn't compatible with Blender 3.6. Try v2.93 instead.

---

We can see in the addon's latest version release notes:

> Fully compatible with Blender 2.93
> Source: [Release 0.19.0 · absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin/releases/tag/0.19.0)

It doesn't mean that it will not work in more recent versions, but it does mean that it wasn't tested for it, and you might have issues.

In our case, the addon is trying to access the "Testing" addon category that was removed back in version 3.5 in think.

So either you wait for the addon's author to update the addon, or you use version 2.93 which you can find on Blender's website:

[Blender 2.93 LTS — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/2-93/)

Since the testing category was removed from v3.5, you might be able to try other 3.x versions, at your own risk.

Alternatively, if you feel comfortable with modifying the addon yourself:

Someone posted a pull request with a fix for v3.6 compatibility ;
[Bump supported blender version to 3.6 by AraHaan · Pull Request #632 · absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin](https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin/pull/632)
You could try to download the modified files and see if it works for you on v3.6. There's no warranty of it working though.